# Libgdx some font letters doesn't appear

Tags: java, android, fonts, libgdx

I have a weird problem with the fonts in my LibGDX game. Some letters in some sizes (I use the same font in different sizes, like 12px, 18px, 22px) do not appear or appear broken.

My code for creating the bitmap fonts:

```
private BitmapFont createFont(String font, int size) {
// load the font
FileHandle fontFile = Gdx.files.internal(font);

FreeTypeFontGenerator.setMaxTextureSize(FreeTypeFontGenerator.NO_MAXIMUM);

FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(fontFile);
FreeTypeFontParameter parameter = new FreeTypeFontParameter();
parameter.size = size;
parameter.minFilter = TextureFilter.Nearest;
parameter.magFilter = TextureFilter.Nearest;
BitmapFont bitmapFont = generator.generateFont(parameter);
bitmapFont.setUseIntegerPositions(false);

generator.dispose();

return bitmapFont;
}
```

Here are a few screenshots of the problem.

[image: screen1]

[image: screen1]

[image: screen3]

As you can see I have tried with different fonts (like Cooper Black STD,Rubik-Bold and more).
Different letters disappear on different phones with different fonts. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Using NO_MAXIMUM is pretty risky--your font simply won't work if the texture size goes above the GPU's maximum. 2048x2048 is safe.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use FreeTypeFontGenerator, but I have a similar problem where the letters won't appear in my game. If you are using Hiero, change the sample text to NEHE or just type the characters you need. Go to Glyph cache, click reset Cache. Set page width and height there to 2048 and Save again. I often get this problem with hiero. For me it is a matter of hit or miss, sometimes I have to do these steps two or three times for it to work. Try going to the font location and check the png files next to the .hiero file, if the letters that don't appear in the game don't appear in those files then for sure it is Hiero not producing the files well. I hope it helps.